# Trying to use skype interviews api, but not working & hitting an error as 502

Tags: webserver, httprequest, webrtc, skype

While running curl to make http post request to skype interviews api, it is hitting an error as ***502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the con[error in command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rco9Z.jpg)tent server.***

I am running a command as "***curl http://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews -H 'skype-apikey: my api key' -d {}***".

By searching, many suggested to check that both IIS versions must be matched, and increase the ARR timeout to 60/120 secs in IIS. Both are not working for this.

Can anyone help me out in using the skype interviews api for performing internal communication like text/audio/video chat, sharing files/screen by any text or video tutorial. Help will be appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: I have implemented skype interviews API in NodeJs.
[First Get your API key and secret:](https://interviews.skype.com/api/get-started)

Step 2: After that create API_KEY and API_SECRET environment variables in the .env file and assign values to them which we got from step 1.

Step 3: Follow the following link for source code to hit  [skype interviews API endpoint](https://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews)

https://gist.github.com/RajuS1ngh/8729fd8f047a20eed0fe1271c982d122